# What is a "rule of right" RPG? (a.k.a. "Oudou RPG")

Tags: terminology

I've seen this term applied to Bravely Default, Final Fantasy and other JRPGs, but I haven't been able to find a definition for it.

Comment: I've never heard this term used before - do you have an example of it?

Comment: I came across the expression in [this article](http://gematsu.com/2013/12/first-look-digimon-story-cyber-sleuth) about an upcoming Digimon RPG. The Japanese term was also used in [this interview with Satoru Iwata](http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=491889).

Comment: Sounds like an RPG where the characters are always trying to do the right thing, and typically the player has little choice.

Answer (score 4):

I have not found a clear answer to this, but I do believe it is a term used by the Japanese, referring to main characters always following their sense of righteousness - rather than giving the player a (moral) choice, which could affect the story.

In an interview with Akitoshi Kawazu, a director working for Square, the term is used to differentiate *SaGa* games from *Final Fantasy*; the latter being called the "rule of right" kind.

Wikipedia explains that *SaGa* games are known for their *"open world exploration, non-linear branching plots, and occasionally unconventional gameplay."* Final Fantasy games, however, are not known to branch out, and are linear in delivering the plot.

Another relevant, if less reliable, source is a post by Samantha Lienhard on the game *Exist Archive*: *"it’s not a “typical rule of right” story. Moral ambiguity and shades of gray since the characters are all evil gods, I guess?"*

Other reviews on *Exist Archive* appear to mention similar features, stating there are choices to be made which influence story elements.

Sources:
http://www.rpgfan.com/features/creatorstalk/index1.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SaGa_(series)
http://www.samanthalienhard.com/2015/07/first-look-at-exist-archive-the-other-side-of-the-sky.html